# matplotlib colormap for just one of the subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting some images with matplotlib as follows:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, len(slices))
    for i, slice in enumerate(slices):
        if i != 3:
            axes[i].imshow(slice.T, cmap="gray", origin="lower")
        else:
            axes[i].imshow(slice.T, cmap="hot", origin="lower")
```

As you can see one of the subplot axes is a heatmap. Is it possible to have a colormap just next to that subplot?

***EDIT:***

Ok, I can do something like:

```
fig.colorbar(im, ax=axes[i])
```

This shows the colorbar but it is disproportionately large! Is it possible to make it the same height as the rest of the plot.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for someone else, here is what worked:

```
im = axes[i].imshow(slice.T, cmap="hot", origin="lower")
fig.colorbar(im, ax=axes[i], fraction=0.046, pad=0.04)
```